# django template exceptions handling

Tags: django, templates

All,

There is a template say x.html
its contes are

```
<form action ="/lookinto/a">
<p >name:</td><td> <input type="text" id=name" name="name"></input></p></tr>
<tr><td>
<p >Section:</td><td> <input type="text" id="section" name="section"></input></p></td></tr>
</form>
```

My question is that when handling,/lookinto/a if i have an exception how to send the data back to x.html

i.e, if name is xx and while saving there is a error how is xx sent back to x.html from views.

Thanks......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Django's [forms framework](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/).